# Gitlab on Window with Docker

Tags: windows, docker, gitlab, continuous-integration

When I try to connect on gitlab on my browser, I received this error :
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu0.2
Invalid SSH identification string
Can someone please help me?

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. Gitlab on windows with docker? But you're trying to connect to gitlab on your browser? If you can edit your question into something clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a [GitLab Docker image](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/docker.html), do note that Docker for Windows is not officially supported.

> There are known issues with volume permissions, and potentially other unknown issues.

Annother approach would be to install GitLab in a WSL2 Linux session on your computer, and see if it answers better to SSH queries.

Comment: Thanks, It Ok with Linux system.

Comment: @JoelKouassi Would that be an appropriate workaround in your case?